# Excel pasting array in cell (after resizing cell to array dimensions)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, paste, transpose

I want to paste a two-dimension array from one cell on, extending the range with RESIZE() to the exact size of the array.

I get a 
run error type 13
type mismatch

```
ReDim conceptArray(1 To 5, NumberOfConcepts + 1)


Dim firstcellofTbl As range
    Set firstcellofTbl = qbaTbl.ListColumns("name").range.iTem(1).Offset(1, 0)
' this is just a test:
'firstcelloftbl is a single cell
firstcellofTbl.Select


firstcellofTbl.Resize(UBound(conceptArray, 2), UBound(conceptArray, 1)) = Application.Transpose(conceptArray)
```

whatever the size of the array is some things I give for granted.
a) firstcellofTbl is just one cell. And exists since the selection works.

the resize size has the same dimensions as the array because it is just resize to the dimensions of the array

c) the resize interchanged both dimensions, therefore the application.transpose

this is the bit of code I added to make tests:

```
 MsgBox UBound(conceptArray, 1)
 MsgBox UBound(conceptArray, 2)
 Dim newrange As range
    Set newrange = firstcellofTbl.Resize(UBound(conceptArray, 2), UBound(conceptArray, 1))
MsgBox newrange.address
```

being: 
    UBound(conceptArray, 1)=5
    UBound(conceptArray, 2)=439

```
newrange.address =$a$3:$E$441
```

which seems to match since the size of the new range is the same as the transpose array

What I am possibly doing wrong?
Thanks a lot

Note:
using this way of pasting data into a listobject (or a sheet) is millions times faster than populating with for-loop, thats the reason for using it.

Comment: What are the values of `LBound(conceptArray, 1)` and `LBound(conceptArray, 2)` ?

Comment: What is type and content of `conceptArray`?

Comment: LBound(conceptArray, 1) =1

Comment: LBound(conceptArray, 2)=0

Comment: conceptarray contains text

Comment: tricky that  Lbound(1) <> Lbound(2) so I tried this: ReDim conceptArray(1 To 5, 1 To NumberOfConcepts + 1)     >>>> same error

Comment: This also works:  firstcellofTbl.Resize(UBound(conceptArray, 2), UBound(conceptArray, 1)).Select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the array was dimensioned as variant.

original:

```
dim conceptarray() as variant
```

solution:

```
dim conceptarray() as string
```

Comment: This can only be half of the truth, you can use variants to write into cells - except if you put something into one of the members that is somehow not valid. Anyhow, good to know that it works now - but if I where you I would try to figure out which value(s) caused this issue.

Comment: i will try to find out if that is the case with an small example.